# Can I resolve a scoped instance from inside a singleton instance in asp.net 5

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I've been using a trick for a while to help with maintaining an audit trail.  In or before the controller, I create a `User` which is bound in some way to the request.  I can use DI to create most of my application as singletons and I can just inject a `Func<User>` wherever I think I need `User` information.  I get the per-request User from the Func and can easily add audit information to everything.

This keeps my domain classes `User` agnostic and lets my DI container act as a `User` management system.

Now I'm using asp.net 5 and I'm having trouble doing the same thing.  Honestly I've never been sure I should be able to do this, but I've gotten used to it.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddScoped<IUser, User>();
    services.AddSingleton<IDependantOnUser, DependantOnUser>
    services.AddScoped<Func<IUser>(c => c.GetRequiredService<IUser>);
}
```

Then in or before my controller I create and populate the user instance.

```
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    public ValuesController(Func<User> userFunc)
    {
        user = userFunc();
        // hydrate user instance as needed
    }
}
```

Then finally, I should have access to the user instance in my singleton object.

```
public class DependantOnUser : IDependantOnUser
{
    public DependantOnUser(Func<User> userFunc)
    {
        user = userFunc();
        // I want this to be the same instance as that generated by the controller
    }
}
```

But I can't get this to work.  Before asp.net 5, I've been using Autofac to achieve this, but haven't had any luck there.  I've tried playing around with transient/scoped/singleton a bit with no luck.  I've even tried resolving my own `IServiceProvider` and using it directly instead of just generating a user with `c => c.GetRequiredService<IUser>`

Everything I do seems to be working with the wrong `IServiceProvider` instance.  Is there a way resolve an instance from a different `ServiceProvider`?  Any other suggestions would also be helpful.

Before you suggest I just register everything using `AddScoped()`, some of the objects between my presentation and persistence layers work a lot better as singletons.

Also I would prefer not to just pass `User` information as a parameter to every method in my domain (we record it with nearly every CRUD operation and pass it with most external calls we make)

Comment: this code: `services.AddScoped<Func<User>(c => c.GetRequiredService<IUser>);` can't compile, please correct it.

Comment: could you not use the decorator approach? which in turn could then call the user?

Answer (score -1):

I believe that it is antipattern to inject scope depedency to singleton one, please refer to Captive Dependencies
[Autofac Captive Dependencies](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/captive-dependencies.html#captive-dependencies)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide context for links. Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)